# change 1 column and leave the rest unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset with one column that I want to change to date-time format. If I use this:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df['product_first_sold_date'],unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
```

`df` will only have this one particular column while all others are removed. Instead, I want to keep the remaining columns unchanged and just apply the `to_datetime` function to one column.

I tried using loc with multiple ways, including this:

```
df.loc[df['product_first_sold_date']] = pd.to_datetime(df['product_first_sold_date'],unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
```

but it throws a key error.

How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['product_first_sold_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['product_first_sold_date'],unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
```

should work i think